# Initialize a dask series

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I was trying to add a column in dask dataframe, but it's not letting me to add columns of type list, so I reached a little bit and found that it would add a dask series. However I'm unable to convert my list to a dask series. Can you help me out?

Comment: It would be better if you gave full details of the code you expected to work, with the manner in which it failed: the code, and the error/traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to a pandas Dataframe if it fits into memory:

```
import pandas as pd  
import dask.dataframe as dd  
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,6,size=(20, 6)),
columns=list('ABCDEF'))   data = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions = 2)

listadd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18, 19, 20] 
listadd = pd.DataFrame(listadd)

data[['G']] = listadd

print data.compute()
```

Comment: Yes, but it won't fit. :/

Comment: The list fits but the Dataframe does not?

Comment: Yes the list fits barely occupying around 75% of the RAM but the dataframe won't while using pandas

Comment: Where is the list coming from? Can you load it directly from a csv or other format? See: https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html

Comment: `dd.from_pandas` also works for Series. Create a `pd.Series` inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

`dask.dataframe.from_pandas(pandas.Series(my_data), npartitions=n)` is what you need. `from_pandas` accepts both `pandas.DataFrame/Series`.